# Does an afterlife exist in the Cosmere?

Tags: cosmere

Brandon Sanderson's Cosmere series features a bunch of immortal people and Gods. (A prevelant theme is mortal people becoming immortal Gods). It also features planets which are considered hell. Many of these elements are based on Mormonism. Which leads me to wonder:

Does Sanderson ever discuss if there is an afterlife postdeath? Not someone who believes in it, but an actual afterlife, confirmed by either someone going there and returning or a third-person omniscient narrator?

Comment: Initially he said there might be, but recently he said that he prefers to leave it ambiguous so as not to pronounce the validity of various characters' beliefs.

Comment: There is a paragraph in the epilogue of The Hero of Ages which touches on this.  I don't know how to hide spoilers, so I won't put it in an answer.

Comment: Without spoiling too much, Mistborn: Secret History and the Lost Metal definitively establish that a person's consciousness persists after death and that it generally goes... somewhere else, though it can stick around in the physical world. At least for Scadrial humans.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/186668/the-concept-of-hell-and-heaven-in-the-mistborn-series https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/204631/whats-the-unknown-god https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/118141/what-happens-when-you-die-in-the-mistborn-series

Answer (score 6):

*Mistborn: Secret History* does not outright confirm an afterlife the way you ask, but is rather suggestive:

> Nearby, an unfortunate skaa woman lurched into the afterlife, then almost immediately *faded*. Her figure stretched, transforming into a white mist that was pulled to a distant dark point. That was how it looked, at least, though the point she stretched toward wasn't a place-not really. It was... Beyond. A location that was somehow distant, pointing away from him no matter where he moved.
> She stretched, then faded away.

> "You didn't think this was the end, did you?" God asked, waving toward the shadowy world. "This is the in between step. After death and before..." "Before what?"
> "Before the Beyond," God said. "The Somewhere Else. Where souls must go."

Chapter 74 of *The Lost Metal* also touches on it:

> ...[He] floated.
> Floated somewhere high...Was that the planet *itself* beneath him?... Felt kinda strange to be all the way up here, in the darkness...

> "I ain't gonna be a ghost, am I?"
> "No. You were Invested when you died, so you will persist a short time, but will soon join the Beyond."

> "That's your last question? Your final request of God before you pass into eternity?"

> With that, [he] stretched into another place, into another time. He stretched into the wind. And into the stars.
> And all endless things

Depending on how you define afterlife, it's also confirmed that the right approach can stop this 'stretching' and allow the dead to persist as a sort of ghost. This is a major plot point in *Mistborn: Secret History* where

> Kelsier

does this. Scholars of the Cosmere are aware of the possibility, though still surprised to see it.

> "It's *you*. You're dead!...One doesn't merely *decide* to become a shadow!" the man exclaimed..."It's an important rite! With requirements and traditions."